# How can I read colors from process's input stream?

Tags: java, inputstream

I am working on a Server launcher. This launcher runs Minecraft servers.
I want to get colors from the server's process's input like windows command prompt. How can I do that?

My server thread:

```
serverThread = new RunnableThread("ServerThread-" + serverName) {
            @Override
            public void onRun() {
                if (!getProcess().isAlive()) {
                    ServerStatusChangeEvent.change(LocalServer.this, StatusType.STOPPED);
                    closePort();
                    if(queryTimerTask != null) queryTimerTask.cancel(false);
                    cancel();
                }
                try {
                    final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(getProcess().getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        String l = line;
                        Platform.runLater(() -> parseLine(l));
                    }
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    //empty catch block
                }
            }
        };
```

Thanks for the answers and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "read colours", but it really depends on what format the information is sent in. Is this HTML? Console escape sequences? Anything else?

Comment: Do you mean rgb color strings like `#FFAABB`?

Comment: I think ANSI colors. I have tried to read input with ansi charset, but it didn't worked.

Comment: But I don't sure about that, thats why I tell you Minecraft.